# Segmented Control

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I was wondering how i can add uiview to a callout right button and also i have coded for segment control for switching maps i keep receiving a break point which say MKMapView selecetedsegmentindex) unrecognised selector.

can u help.

code:

```
- (IBAction)setMap:(id)sender{

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;

        case 1:
            map.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;

        case 2:
            map.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you are using that SegmentedControl (assuming it is a SegmentedControl you have wired up to that action). Please post the code you are using for the map (I suspect the map.mapType assignment you are doing is invalid).

Answer (score 2):

That would suggest that the `sender` is not a `UISegmentedControl`.  Add the following to see what it is:

```
NSLog(@"Sender=%@", NSStringFromClass([sender class]));
```